# 12V piezo buzzer not working using ESP32

Tags: mosfet, esp32, buzzer

I'm trying to make my buzzer sound when hooked up to 12V and a MOSFET in between but I'm perfectly failing. I'm using GPIO15 of my ESP32 WROOM to send a PWM signal to the MOSFET but nothing really happens. Would someone be so kind to tell me what is going wrong here?

[image: Schematics]

I'm using the Arduino environment and VS code and the simple code looks like so:

```C
    void beep(int frequency, int duration) {
      tone(mosfetPin, frequency); // Generate a tone with the specified frequency
      delay(duration);            // Keep the tone playing for the specified duration
      noTone(mosfetPin);          // Stop the tone
    }
```

Interestingly, it works when I connect the buzzer pin (GPIO15) directly to the buzzer. This is not the original intention, though, and the 3.3V of the ESP32 is keeping the volume at a very low level.

[Buzzer](https://www.digikey.ch/de/products/detail/mallory-sonalert-products-inc/AST0760MCTRQ/11567566?s=N4IgTCBcDaIIIGUAqAGA7ANhQWQMJICUBFEAXQF8g)

Comment: Have you checked the output of the ESP32, or the voltage across the buzzer? What frequency are you generating?

Comment: An inductor of around 100 mH parallel to the buzzer will help there.

Comment: if it's a 12 V buzzer, then why do you use  resistor with a 12 V supply?

Answer (score 8):

The buzzer has a piezoelectric disc so the transistor driver as drawn is not suitable for piezoelectric buzzers. It would work for a normal speaker.

The driver will turn on once and the piezo capacitance is charged to 12V, so there is a single click.

There is nothing in the circuit to discharge the piezo capacitance.

When you connect it directly to the GPIO pin, it works because the push-pull output will both charge the capacitance to 3.3V and discharge it to 0V.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Justme seems to be correct about the piezo device.  According to the Mallory [(English) AST0760MCTRQ datasheet](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/59/AST0760MCTRQ_DS.pdf) there is "NO CIRCUITRY", meaning that there is no internal driver circuitry, it is only the piezo element.

However, there are a few other driver options to get this working. One simple option is to place about a 1k resistor in parallel with the buzzer leads, this allows the internal capacitance to discharge. There are a few other methods discussed in this document: [An Overview of Driver Circuits for Piezo Transducer Buzzers .](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/industry-articles/an-overview-of-driver-circuits-for-piezo-transducer-buzzers/)

Also, since the resonant frequency is listed as 6kHz this will be the most efficient frequency to use for the driving signal.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't have enough voltage to turn on the transistor. 2N7002s can be driven from 3.3V but R42/R43 drop the gate drive to ~2.7V. Move R43 to the "other side" of R42 and try again, or use a different transistor.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like it.

I am using a piezo buzzer too, but mine is 5V and I am using a BC846 NPN to drive it with my ESP32S3 pin.

[image]

Note that I am using a diode in parallel with the buzzer.

It works perfectly with the same simple code.

Comment: Note that if the part.nr is correct in your schematic, it's a magnetic buzzer not a piezo.

Comment: This schematic will not work with the piezo either.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, your feedback is very much appreciated!

I now tried a 1K reset transisor in parallel to the buzzer pins as proposed in the previous message and it works!

See option 1:
https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/industry-articles/an-overview-of-driver-circuits-for-piezo-transducer-buzzers/